# WebSphere: How to get the decoded page name in doView portlet method?

Tags: java, portlet, portal, websphere-portal

I have a requirement where I need to get the page name from the request in the doView method and redirect it to page_name_SUFIX but I can't find a way to decode the WebSphere URL

When I request the view for 'pageName' I have to do something like this:

```
public void doView(RenderRequest req, RenderResponse res) {
    String decodedURL = decodeURL(req); // This is the method that I need, decodedURL should be 'pageName'
    (...)
}
```

I am working on WebSphere 8.0 and I've tried the following without results.

http://wpcertification.blogspot.com.ar/2010/05/getting-name-of-page-where-your-portlet.html (Here i've got the page title, but i don't know how to get the name)

[WebSphere Portal decode url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12848126/websphere-portal-decode-url) (I've decoded the URL but I can't find the page name in the XML)

There's some way to achieve this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

So the question is of scope,  from above it is unclear if you mean pageName as in the uniqueName of the page?  If so once you have the objectid in a string or the actual object you can get the uniqueName from that object.

here is code to get the objectId of the current page
public ObjectID getCurrentPage(PortletRequest request,
            PortletResponse response) throws StateException, NamingException,
            IOException {
        ObjectID oId = null;
        try {
            NavigationSelectionModelProvider provider = getNavigationSelectionModelProvider();

```
        NavigationSelectionModel model = provider
                .getNavigationSelectionModel(request, response);
        NavigationNode node = (NavigationNode) model.getSelectedNode();
        oId = node.getObjectID();
    } catch (ModelException e) {
        System.err.println("The current page could not be located = " + e);
    }

    return oId;
}
```

Now if your question is about a portlet parameter called pageName then it should be in the decoded url.  is it the uniqueName you are looking for?  that will not be in the xml but you can get that from the objectid object

Comment: Thank  you for your answer. Actually I need the uniqueName. I've tried your code and oId.getUniqueName() returns null

Comment: So two things, 1)can swallow the null, not sure if it is or not a link below has my helpers in it with the full code. 2) Are you sure one is defined?  have you outputed the objectid as a string and searched for that in xmlaccess to see what is defined?  there is the possibility that you are on a derived page and not on the parent page you think you are on leading to no uniquename returned.  The first is are you getting an OID returned,https://connections.asponte.com/blogs/asppontecom/entry/Portal_8_0_and_8_5_Advanced_URL_Generation_Helper_classes?lang=en_us

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to get the page id/uniqueName by using a doView method similar to this:

```
public void doView(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response) throws PortletException, IOException {
    // Set the MIME type for the render response
    response.setContentType(request.getResponseContentType());
    PortletServiceHome nsh = null;
    javax.naming.Context ctx;
    boolean serviceAvailable = false;
    try {
        ctx = new javax.naming.InitialContext();
        nsh = (PortletServiceHome)ctx.lookup("portletservice/com.ibm.portal.portlet.service.model.NavigationSelectionModelProvider");
        serviceAvailable = true;


    } catch(NameNotFoundException nnfe) {
        nnfe.printStackTrace();

    } catch(NamingException ne) {
        ne.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Check if portlet session exists
    ShowPageLayoutPortletSessionBean sessionBean = getSessionBean(request);
    if( sessionBean==null ) {
        response.getWriter().println("<b>NO PORTLET SESSION YET</b>");
        return;
    } else if(!serviceAvailable) {
        response.getWriter().println("<b>NO SERVICE AVAILABLE</b>");
        return;
    }

    try {
    NavigationSelectionModelProvider nsProvider = (NavigationSelectionModelProvider) nsh.getPortletService(NavigationSelectionModelProvider.class);
    NavigationSelectionModel navmodel = nsProvider.getNavigationSelectionModel(request, response);
    NavigationNode navNode = (NavigationNode)navmodel.getSelectedNode();
    ContentPage contentPage = (ContentPage)navNode.getContentNode();
    ObjectID pageId = contentPage.getObjectID();



    // Invoke the JSP to render
    PortletRequestDispatcher rd = getPortletContext().getRequestDispatcher(getJspFilePath(request, VIEW_JSP));
    rd.include(request,response);

    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```